# Command not doing anything

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to make a command that would send a message to the sender, but it isn't working.

Here's the main class:

```
public void onEnabled() {
getLogger().info("Enabled!");
}

public boolean onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
        sender.sendMessage("Hey there " + sender);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your *plugin.yml* but if it is right then it should work if you change from:

```
onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String label, String[] args)
```

To:

```
onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
```

*Order matters because otherwise Bukkit will call your onCommand wrongly.*

Also, to show the sender's name you need to change from:

```
sender.sendMessage("Hey there " + sender);
```

To:

```
sender.sendMessage("Hey there " + sender.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onCommand()` method should return a `boolean`. You just need to return `true` or `false`. `true` means that the command has done something, so you should return that as part of the `if` statement. Else just return `false`.
The following should work:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) {
        sender.sendMessage("Hey there " + sender.getName());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this doesn't work, try posting your *plugin.yml* and the error you're getting because that might tell us more.

Comment: Thanks, I just forgot to insert the "return false" outside the if here because in my code there was but the problem was in the order of the onCommand arguments